# Data from array not appear?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to fetch data from the database and display it in Home.vue file,
when go to Vue tab in browser (Hotels:Array[0])

file: Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <form>
      <div class="inputcontainer">
        <input
          class="searchc"
          type="text"
          v-model="searchcity"
          placeholder="Search by city..."
        />

      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card" v-for="htl in searchcityfunc" :key="htl.id">
          <img :src="htl.img" alt="Hotel Image" style="width:100%" />
          <h1 class="name">{{ htl.name }}</h1>
          <p class="price">{{ htl.price }}</p>
          <p class="city">{{ htl.city }}</p>
          <p class="button"><button>Reed more</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

import axios from "axios";
var Hotels = [];

export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      searchcity: "",
      Hotels,
    };
  },
  methods:{
    fetchAllData: function(){
      axios.post('http://localhost//web//action.php',{
        action:'fetchall',
      }).then(function(response){
        Hotels = response.data;
        console.log(Hotels);
      })
    },

    searchcityfunc() {
      return Hotels.filter((srh) =>
        this.searchcity != "" ? !srh.city.indexOf(this.searchcity) : ""
      );
    },
  },
  created:function(){
this.fetchAllData();
  }
  ,
};
</script>
```

From my PHP file, I connected to the database and fetched all the records and encoded them

file: action.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$DBname = "HotelsDB";


$connection = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$DBname);

$received_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$data = array();

if($received_data->action == 'fetchall'){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Hotels";

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row;
}

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

and when trying to search by city nothing appears and Hotels array is (0).

Comment: `Hotels` is constructed outside of the Vue instance, so it is not reactive to Vue. `hotels: Hotels` would be better and `this.hotels = response.data`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy new error appear "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'hotels' of undefined"

Comment: comment   `Hotels = response.data; console.log(Hotels);` and log `response`

Comment: аnd left onе of Hotels (this.Hotels  or var Hotels)

Comment: It's lexical scoping. `function (response)` scopes `this` to the closure, where as `((response) => ` would scope `this` to the `Vue` instance.

Comment: Just to build on previous comments, unless I'm missing something, I don't see why you are defining 'var Hotels' in the first place.  It seems you could just define `data() { return { searchcity: '', hotels: [ ] } }`